# fs writefile new line not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

i want log my user command

```
function saveLog (nick, command) {
    var file = 'log/' + nick + '.log';
    var datetime = '[' + getDateTime() + '] ';
    var text = datetime + command + '\r\n';
    fs.writeFile(file, text, function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log(text);
    });
}
```

the function i made is fine, but
it didnt save the log in new line, its just replace text / rewrite the file.
whats im missing ?

thanks

Comment: You need `fs.appendFile`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`fs.writeFile` writes a WHOLE NEW file. What your are looking for is `fs.appendFile` which will make the file if it doesn't exist and append to it. Documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_filename_data_options_callback).

```
function saveLog (nick, command) {
    var file = 'log/' + nick + '.log';
    var datetime = '[' + getDateTime() + '] ';
    var text = datetime + command + '\r\n';
    fs.appendFile(file, text, function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log('successfully appended "' + text + '"');
    });
}
```