# Send same json in the file at each script execution

Tags: javascript, json

I'm writting a JSON and adding into a file.

I don't know how can I add the same JSON in the same array...

When I execute the script, i need to add the new value into the file and not overwritting

I just need to append the JSON. If I use appenFile, create 3 array and I need only 1 array (Look expected result)

Need help, thanks

```
var table = []

table.push({"executionDate":date,
  "issueID":key,
  "priority":{
     "jira": priority, 
     "computed":score1
  },
  "expectedValue":{
     "jira": expected, 
     "computed":score2
  }
})

var json = JSON.stringify(table);
fs.writeFile('myjsonfile.json', json, 'utf8', function (err) {
  if (err) console.error(err)
  })
```

Actual result:

```
 [{
  "executionDate": 25 / 03 / 2019,
  "issueID": 1,
  "priority": {
     "jira": important,
     "computed": 10
  },
  "expectedValue": {
     "jira": expected,
     "computed": 20
  }
}]
```

Expected resultat if I execute the script 2 times:

```
[{
  "executionDate": 25 / 03 / 2019,
  "issueID": 1,
  "priority": {
     "jira": important,
     "computed": 10
  },
  "expectedValue": {
     "jira": expected,
     "computed": 20
  }
},
{
  "executionDate": 25 / 03 / 2019,
  "issueID": 1,
  "priority": {
     "jira": important,
     "computed": 10
  },
  "expectedValue": {
     "jira": expected,
     "computed": 20
  }
},
{
  "executionDate": 25 / 03 / 2019,
  "issueID": 1,
  "priority": {
     "jira": important,
     "computed": 10
  },
  "expectedValue": {
     "jira": expected,
     "computed": 20
  }
}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fs writefile new line not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30283509/fs-writefile-new-line-not-working)

Comment: I f I use appendFile, he creates me 3 array and I need only 1 array with all element inside ... (Look expected result)

Comment: Then show how you used `appendFile`.

Comment: I just changed "writeFile" by "AppendFile" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if i understand it well but a fast solution is:

```html
<html>
<script>
var table = [];
console.log(table);

function findInArrAndPush(obj){
 const found = table.some(el => el.issueID === obj.issueID);
 if (!found) table.push(obj);
 return table;
}
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
 var id = i;

 var objToAdd = {"executionDate":"01-01-1000",
  "issueID":id,
  "priority":{
     "jira": "1", 
     "computed":"1"
  },
  "expectedValue":{
     "jira": "2", 
     "computed":"2"
  }
};
console.log(findInArrAndPush(objToAdd));
//ADD TO FILE HERE
}

  </script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

the only thing you have to do here is print the result to the file.

Comment: Yes this is the idea, but logically, the time must be different (speaking about seconds for example) because you can't execute in the same time ...

Comment: I think that the only change that you have to do is to instead write json in the file, write findInArrAndPush(objToAdd), and doing table, equal to read the origin file. I dont know if you understand what Im trying to say

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I try do to something and if i'm block, I ask you for more information :)

Comment: No problem, just dont forget to vote positive if my answer was usefull :P

Comment: Yes of course
I put: fs.writeFile('myjsonfile.json', findInArrAndPush(objToAdd), 'utf8', function (err) {if (err) console.error(err)})
But in my file, there is [object Object]

Comment: Ok then is because you are missing JSON.stringify();

Comment: Just for notice, I don't want to specificate the time to push because I need to do manually ...
And it's overwritting ...

Comment: The thing of working with files is that you only can read data and write data again, but never do logic inside it, its a text plain file. So by definition it will be overwitten. And to do it mannually just add the write procces to a function and pass the object to write as parameter when you press a button for example.    With append it will add to a file, the result of merge 2 files, but its impossible to filter the repited elements if you dont overwrite.